# Can enter wp-admin when logged in with custom ajax

Tags: wp-admin

I logged in my site with custom ajax. Then try to connect my wp-admin, the page redirect me to login.php

My custom ajax function in php;

```
function ajax_login(){
check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' );
$info = array();
$info['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
$info['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
$info['remember'] = true;
if((trim($info['user_login']) == "" || $info['user_password'] == "" || strlen(trim($info['user_login'])) < 3 || strlen($info['user_password']) < 6 )){
    echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Error')));
}else{
  $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
  if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
      echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Error')));
  } else {
      wp_set_current_user($user_signon->ID);
      echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Error')));
  }
}
  die();
}


  function ajax_auth_init(){
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );
  }

 if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
 add_action('init', 'ajax_auth_init');
 }
```

Why I can't connect directly to wp-admin?

Comment: Reload the page on ajax success after use is logged in. Write reload script below wp_set_current_user($user_signon->ID); this line in code.

Comment: I'm already using that. But I got it. See my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I got it. 
Just I need to change

```
$user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
```

with

```
$user_signon = wp_signon( $info, is_ssl() ? true : false );
```